# How to call multi block with in one tab in admin edit page in magento

Tags: magento, adminhtml, magento-1.9.1

I want to call two section/block within one tab. Can anyone help me to how can I get achieve this one?
Please find attached screen-shot to more detail.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in tab section write code only for one tab like:

```
<namespacename>_<modulename>_Block_Adminhtml_<modulename>_Edit_Tabs

$this->addTab('form_section', array(
                   'label' => '<tab lable>',
                   'title' => '<tab title>',
                   'content' => $this->getLayout()
     ->createBlock('<modulename>/adminhtml_<modulename>_edit_tab_form')
     ->toHtml()
         ));
```

and then write all code related to the two tab in this folder structure file:

```
<namespacename>_<modulename>_Block_Adminhtml_<modulename>_Edit_Tab_Form
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please let me know how can I call grid in this block now with custom block?

Comment: because i can not understand your requirement Can you please give me your artifact requirement ?

Comment: I want to show a custom calculation result in first block and product grid serializer in second block

Comment: May be you wont to grid and form in one tab may i right ?